# Telling which sum is greater, the odd or even powers of a Poisson random variable

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

Let $X$ be a Poisson random variable with parameter $\lambda$, then we have that

$$P(X=k)=e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$$

and we know that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P(X=k)=1$, now, this can be splitted into

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P(X=k)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty P(X=2k) + \sum_{k=0}^\infty P(X=2k+1)=1$$

then we compute

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty P(X=2k)= e^{-\lambda}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^{2i}}{(2i)!} = e^{-\lambda} \cosh(\lambda)$$

therefore

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty P(X=2k+1)=1-e^{-\lambda} \cosh(\lambda)=\frac{1}{2}(1-e^{-2\lambda})$$

from this we conclude that the even sum is greater that the odd sum.

My question is, Are there more approaches to do this? only using the following 
$$P(X=k+1)=\frac{\lambda}{k+1}P(X=k)$$

I was thinking to use a Gauss's trick here but I can't figure out how.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: and $P(X=0)=?$ ?

Comment: Well we only allow positive integers right?

Comment: The parameter $k$ should start from $0$, not from $1$... (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution)

Comment: Yes sorry :) but the idea and the question are clear isn't?

Comment: Ready :) edited

Answer (score 1):

Using your methods, we can find the odd sum in the same way as we find the even sum:
$$\mathbb P(X \text{ odd}) = \mathrm e^{-\lambda} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}=\mathrm e^{-\lambda} \sinh \lambda$$
And this shows quite easily that the even probability is greater.

From an intuitive point of view, one may ask why an even result should be more likely than an odd one. This essentially stems from the smallest possible value that $X$ may take being 0. As $\lambda$ increases, we find that the difference between the probabilities decreases exponentially and that the bias between odd and even results only manifests itself when the expectation of $X$ is close to 0.

Ok. Here is how to do it under some conditions with the relation you gave at the end of your question. First we define:
$$p_k = \mathbf P(X=k).$$

Thus, $$p_{k+1} = \frac\lambda{k+1} p_{k}.$$ Now let $$s_k =p_k+p_{k+2}+p_{k+4}+\cdots$$

Combining the two, we see that
$$s_{k+1} = \lambda((k+1)^{-1}p_k +(k+3)^{-1}p_{k+2}+\cdots)$$
But as $k\ge0,$ we have:
$$s_{k+1}\le\frac\lambda{k+1}(p_k+p_{k+2}+\cdots).$$
Thus $$s_1\le\lambda s_0$$

This gives the desired result for $\lambda>1$. I'll leave it up to you to see if you can finish it off

Comment: Right but can you explain more the intuitive part (can you give the math behind) and why the difference decreases as an exponential please :)

Comment: $\cosh-\sinh=\mathrm e^-$

Comment: Right but imagine you don't have $cosh$ and $sinh$ handly that is why this is a new approach :) only using the relation I gave

Comment: Ok then just look at the power series for P(even)-P(odd) and then just stare at it and realise it looks a lot like $\mathrm e^{-\lambda}$

Comment: Ok, and where you used the relation?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you meant by the previous comment. I can't think of how to use the relation you have right now but converting it to give P(X=k+2) in terms of P(X=k) would probably be a good start.

Comment: Ok, what about the explanation of your answer (read my first comment please) :)

Comment: By previous, I meant initial

Comment: Can you explain the math behind that intuitive part please :)

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: I'll check it jus give me some time :) please don't disconnect :)

Comment: I am back :), but what is the part that I have to finish?

Comment: $\lambda\le 1.$

Comment: Where did you use the condition $\lambda >1$ ?

Comment: The final conclusion

Comment: Sorry but I can't figure the step :( I really apologize

Comment: You want to prove $s_0<s_1$ so see how to get from the last line to that

Comment: Ok I´ll be back just give me some time to get it please :)

Comment: Get it, the thing is that I can't use the above approach for $\lambda \le 1$ right?

Comment: I don't know. I suspect that you might get a little bit of success but that you'd eventually be doing the sinh/cosh way but in longhand. There is however, only one way to find out what will and will not work

Comment: Can you clarify your comment please, because I don't get it :)

Comment: Firstly that I don't think this line of inquiry will tell you anything that you didn't already know and secondly that it doesn't necessarily matter what I think as I may be wrong and that the only way to determine whether this line of inquiry is a good one is to actually try following it

Comment: yes, I agree with you, and I have already understand your way to do it  the thing is that the way that you did the above I think wont work to do the other case or may be one just argue that in the first inequality one gets the other way around since $\lambda \le 1$ and then...it doesn't work right ?

Comment: May be the answer to the above is that I need to switch the indices so that I get $s_0 > \lambda s_1$ right?

Comment: The thing is that I am having troubles with that :)

Comment: And in fact we want $s_0 > s_1$ right? So I think you did the case $\lambda < 1$