# How to prove that $\frac{\lambda}{k} s_{k} < s_{k-1}$

Tags: probability, inequality

Using @DanRobertson's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1895108/telling-which-sum-is-greater-the-odd-or-even-powers-of-a-poisson-random-variabl) first we define:
$$p_k = \mathbf P(X=k).$$

where $\mathbf P(X=k)$ is the probability of a Poisson random variable, then we have the relation,

$$p_{k+1} = \frac\lambda{k+1} p_{k}.$$

Now let $$s_k =p_k+p_{k+2}+p_{k+4}+\cdots$$

So we have that

$$s_{k+1} = \lambda((k+1)^{-1}p_k +(k+3)^{-1}p_{k+2}+\cdots)$$

And since $k\ge0,$ we get:
$$s_{k+1}\le\frac\lambda{k+1}(p_k+p_{k+2}+\cdots).$$

Therefore $$s_1\le\lambda s_0$$

then for $\lambda<1$, $s_1 <s_0$. But in the case where $\lambda>1$, How can I prove that $\frac{\lambda}{k} s_{k} < s_{k-1}$? so that $s_1 <s_0$ anyway

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote above, *for all* $\lambda>0$ it holds: 
$$
s_{k}=\lambda\sum_{n \ge 0}\frac{p_{k-1+2n}}{k+2n}<\frac{\lambda}{k}\sum_{n \ge 0}p_{k-1+2n}=\frac{\lambda s_{k-1}}{k}.
$$
In particular, if $\lambda \le k$ then
$$
s_{k}<\frac{\lambda s_{k-1}}{k}\le \frac{k s_{k-1}}{\lambda}.
$$
Otherwise, if $\lambda>k$ the claim is false. Indeed, for $k=1$, $s_1+s_0=1$ and
$$
s_0=e^{-\lambda}\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{\lambda^{2n}}{(2n)!}=e^{-\lambda}\left(\frac{e^{\lambda}+e^{-\lambda}}{2}\right)=\frac{1+e^{-2\lambda}}{2};
$$
but, on the other hand, the inequality
$$
\frac{\lambda}{1} s_1<s_0
$$
is false whenever $\lambda$ is sufficiently large (indeed in that case both $s_0$ and $s_1$ are approximately $1/2$).

Comment: This is the inequality the OP should be getting, but not the one he/she seems to want.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Probably I misunderstood; the correct question is $s_k<\alpha s_{k-1}$ with $\alpha=k/\lambda$ instead of $\lambda/k$?

Comment: Well, that was wrong...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, but then Is my claim false? and another thing why the downvote?

Comment: @user162343 You asked to prove that $\lambda s_k < ks_{k-1}$ for all integers $k \ge 1$ and all reals $\lambda>0$, which is false.. Please edit your question

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti I have said in my post that the above inequality is for $\lambda >1$ right, I know that this maybe doesn't change a thing of your proof but just make it clearer. Then how can I proceed in proving the case $\lambda >1$?

Comment: @user162343 Can you write explicitly what you want to prove?

Comment: Please see the link in my post first  :)

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti what do you think?

Comment: @user162343  To sum up, what you are asking is simply "another proof of $s_1<s_0$". Ok, the inequality $s_k<\lambda s_{k-1}/k$ (which is not the one you wrote at the end of your post) is sufficient only in the case $\lambda\le 1$ (the case $\lambda=1$ is included). The case $\lambda>1$ does not work with this method. Moreover, as $\lambda \to \infty$, then $s_1-s_0 \to 0$. Can I ask why don't you like the direct method?

Comment: Ok so what you are saying is that the proof is complete with @DanRobertson answer? And well just wondering new methods here :) with out using sinh or cosh :)

Comment: You don't need to recall that the involved expression is the hyperbolic cosine, but only that $\sum_{n\ge 0}x^n/n!=e^x$. Indeed, also $\sum_{n\ge 0}(-x)^n/n!=e^{-x}$, hence summing the two expression you obtain (up to a factor $2$) only the sum on even indexes, which is exactly what you need to compute $s_0$.

Comment: Can you clarify please ? :)

Comment: If $n$ is an odd index then $x^n/n! + (-x)^n/n!=0$..

Comment: yes I agree but then... :)

Comment: It is all you need to compute $s_0$ explicitly: $
s_0=e^{-\lambda}\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{\lambda^{2n}}{(2n)!}=e^{-\lambda}\left(\frac{e^{ \lambda }+e^{-\lambda}}{2}\right)=\frac{1+e^{-2\lambda}}{2}
$

Comment: Ok, but doing that is exactly what I wrote in the link of my post right? I'll be back just give me some time please :)

Comment: Yes, I think you added the link after my answer, anyway, nevermind :) Note that the title of the thread is wrong, please edit it